# How to make a JFrame window appear only after I press the JButton of the previous JFrame window?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

My program is about a supermarket. When I compile the program, both the JFrame windows 'f1' and 'f2' appear on the screen. However I want JFrame window 'f1' to appear first and then after clicking on the JButton 'b1' of 'f1' window, I want the JFrame window 'f2' to come. Below is the delivery() method of my program:

```
public static void delivery()
{
    final JFrame f1 = new JFrame("Name");
    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(20, 40, 10, 8);
    f1.setLayout(grid);
    f1.setVisible(true);
    f1.setSize(600,200);
    f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    f1.setLocation(700,450);

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();

    final JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Enter your name: ");

    final JTextField jt1 = new JTextField(20);

    JButton b1 = new JButton("Ok");
    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            input1 = jt1.getText();
            f1.dispose();
        }
    });

    p1.add(b1);
    p1.add(l1);
    p1.add(jt1);
    f1.add(p1);

    final JFrame f2 = new JFrame("Address");
    f2.setVisible(true);
    f2.setSize(600,200);
    f2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    f2.setLocation(700,450);

    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();

    final JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Enter your address: ");

    final JTextField jt2 = new JTextField(20);

    JButton b2 = new JButton("Ok");
    b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            input2 = jt2.getText();
            f2.dispose();
        }
    });

    p2.add(b1);
    p2.add(l2);
    p2.add(jt2);
    f2.add(p2);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The ordered stuff will be delivered to " +input1+ " who lives in: " +input2 , "Delivery" , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for shopping at Paradise 24/7. Hope to see you again." , "Shopping Done!" , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of code that makes a frame appear is this

```
f1.setVisible(true);
```

You have this for both frames within your delivery method.

To make one appear after the other change this so that one gets set to visible and the other gets unset within the code for the button ie (you will obviously have to declare f2 before this though)

```
 b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        input1 = jt1.getText();
        f1.dispose();
        //f1.setVisible(false); // or dispose if you no longer need it
        f2.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Just a suggestion: A better approach maybe to use a [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html). This would allow you to get the input form the user wait for response, and then prompt for the next input. [Click here for tutorial on Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

You may also want to look at some layouts when adding components your frames/panels. [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html), [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html), [FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html)

Comment: I am a beginner in Java. I actually had no clue about JFrame and ActionListener but I have somehow managed to learn it via YouTube. So I don't really no much of Java. I only know the very basics of it.

Comment: @siddhu99 Then I would recommend taking the time to read through [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) and [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the code `f2.setVisible(true);` in `actionPerformed()` of the Button.

For e.g.

```
f1.setBounds(whatever);
f2.setBounds(whatever);

//add button in JFrame and actionListener
f1.setVisible(true);
f2.setVisible(false);

actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
     f2.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you must read [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) first and read some good ebooks for Java Beginner like Java 2 Complete Reference, O'Really - Java Swing will be helpful for you